# How do I convert a date format in SQL to YYYY,MM,DD but with commas instead of forward slashes, full stops or dashes?

Tags: sql, date-formatting

I need to get an output date format in SQL as YYYY,MM,DD, e.g. following example:

```
2014,03,10
```

I need there to be commas separating the integers, not dashes, forward slashes or full stops.  I've already got the date sequence part right - `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) AS [YYYY,MM,DD]` - but I need to replace the full stops with commas.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jenny

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: do it in the presentation layer, where it belongs.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: i'm fairly new to SQL so I don't know what a 'presentation layer' is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace`:

```
SELECT replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102), '.', ',') AS [YYYY,MM,DD]
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this was a perfect answer.  Did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_date, '%Y,%m,%d') FROM [...]
```

Comment: The problem is that this would produce `'2014,3,10'` for the example in the question, rather than `'2014,03,10'`.

Comment: Edited... Use the DATE_FORMAT function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @gioradnolima . . . The syntax suggests that the query is SQL Server, not MySQL.  I do *wish* that SQL Server had `date_format()`, but it doesn't.